# Why do you need to use Initializers in Swift?

Tags: swift

Having this first struct:

```
struct example {
    var name: String
    var number: Int
    func show (data: String) {
        print(data)
    }
}

let obj = example(name: "Hello World", number: 2)
```

And this second struct:

```
struct example2 {
    var nameModified: String
    var numberModified: Int
    init(nameFrom: String, numberFrom: Int) {
        nameModified = nameFrom + "World"
        numberModified = numberFrom + 1
    }
}

let obj2 = example2(nameFrom: "Hello", numberFrom: 1)
```

I can't see the difference between having an initializer method and not having it. 
May I'm not seeing the proper functionality for that. Is there anyone who could point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You **always** have at least one initializer, you just not always have explicitly write for `struct`ures. But it's always there.

Comment: Please read about [Default Initializers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID213) in the Swift book.

Comment: what language do you come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In structs, the default init function is inferred based on the properties of the struct.
So you can either write this init function, or leave it out:

```
init(nameFrom: String, numberFrom: Int) { ... }
```

The benefit of adding an init function explicitly, is that you're able to execute code within the init function, if that's what you'd like to do.
Also, you can of course add custom `convenience init` functions.

Note, however, that this is not a feature of classes. For those, you will always have to explicitly write an initializer.

You can safely do:

```
struct Example {
    var name: String
    var number: Int
}
```

...yet this:

```
class Example {
    var name: String
    var number: Int
}
```

...will throw the following error:

> Class 'Example' has no initializers

Instead, you'd have to do:

```
class Example {
    var name: String
    var number: Int

    init(name: String, number: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
    }
}
```

If, however, you'd provide default values for the properties inside the class, you would not have to write an explicit initializer:

```
class Example {
    var name: String?
    var number: Int = 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Swift, both classes and structs that adhere to the criteria below contain a default initializer.

> Swift provides a default initializer for any structure or class that
>   provides default values for all of its properties and does not provide
>   at least one initializer itself. The default initializer simply
>   creates a new instance with all of its properties set to their default
>   values.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html